# Dense SIFT Bag of Features

Tags: opencv, sift, bag

I am trying to do dense SIFT feature extraction with bag of features (BoF) using OpenCV. The idea is to follow [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619039/Bag-of-Features-Descriptor-on-SIFT-Features-with-O) tutorial but just a little change to use dense SIFT features instead.

As you know, the first part in the BoF paradigm, we create the visual dictionary. So the code with some modification goes like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<dirent.h>

#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>

// This is a dense sampling of SIFT descriptors.



using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void dense_SIFT_BoW(Mat img_raw, Mat &featuresUnclustered);
void SIFT_matcher(Mat img_raw, Mat &dictionary, Mat &bowTry, Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> &matcher);

#define DICTIONARY_BUILD 0

int main()
{
    #if DICTIONARY_BUILD == 1
    initModule_nonfree();

     // Store detected image key points.

    Mat featuresUnclustered;

    DIR *pDir = nullptr;
    string imgDir("D:/WillowActions Backup/Willow 300_200/sample/");// Directory of your images. (Change this according to where you images are)
    string imgPath;
    pDir = opendir(imgDir.c_str());
    string dirName;

    Mat img_raw; // Our loaded image.

    struct dirent *pent = nullptr; // dirent structure for directory manipulation.

    if(pDir == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "Directory pointer could not be initialized correctly ! " << endl; // Some checking.
        return 1;
    }

    int count = 0;

    cout << "Please WAIT..." << endl;

    while((pent = readdir(pDir)) != nullptr)
    {
        if(pent == nullptr)
        {
            cout << " Dirent struct could not be initialized correctly !" << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        if(!strcmp(pent->d_name,".")||!strcmp(pent->d_name,".."))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            // LOOP trough the directory to read image one by one and extract their Dense SIFT
            dirName = pent->d_name;
            imgPath = imgDir+dirName; // Overall image path... feed this to imread();
            img_raw = imread(imgPath,1);// read the image to extract denseSIFT features
            dense_SIFT_BoW(img_raw, featuresUnclustered);
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout << "Number of files in folder: " << count << endl;

   cout << featuresUnclustered.size() << endl;

   //Construct BOW k-means trainer
    // the number of bags
    int dictionarySize = 5;

    //define term criteria
    TermCriteria tc(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 0.001);

    // retry number
    int retries = 1;

    //necessary flags
    int flags = KMEANS_PP_CENTERS;

    //Create the BOW trainer
    BOWKMeansTrainer bowTrainer(dictionarySize, tc, retries, flags);

    //cluster the feature vectors
    Mat dictionary = bowTrainer.cluster(featuresUnclustered);

    //store the vocabulary
    FileStorage fs("D:/WillowActions Backup/Willow 300_200/Dense.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);
    fs << "Vocabulary" << dictionary;
    fs.release();
```

The function dense_SIFT_BoW(img_raw, featuresUnclustered) is defined as:

```
void dense_SIFT_BoW(Mat img_raw,Mat &featuresUnclustered)
{

    Mat descriptors; // Store our dense SIFT descriptors.
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;

    DenseFeatureDetector detector(12.f, 1, 0.1f, 10);

    detector.detect(img_raw,keypoints);

    Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> descriptorExtractor = DescriptorExtractor::create("SIFT");

    descriptorExtractor->compute(img_raw,keypoints,descriptors);

    descriptors.setTo(0, descriptors < 0);
    descriptors = descriptors.reshape(0,1);

    featuresUnclustered.push_back(descriptors);


}
```

What it essentially does is loop trough a folder for each image, extract dense SIFT features for all images and do K-means clustering. This builds the visual dictionary.

This part of the code works fine for me. I.e. In a folder with 256 image files I get a dictionary of size 256 x 76800 (rows by columns: cluster centers). After Creating the dictionary.

Now, Having created the Dictionary. Following the BoF paradigm, We want to again extract dense SIFT and do matching against the Dictionary just created. For this i use nearest neighbors. It is also essentially looping a folder for images. This is what i have:

```
#else

    Mat dictionary;
    FileStorage fs("D:/WillowActions Backup/Willow 300_200/Dic_Dense.xml", FileStorage::READ);
    fs["Vocabulary"] >> dictionary;
    fs.release();

    //Create a nearest neighbor matcher
    Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher(new FlannBasedMatcher);

    //Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> descriptorExtractor = DescriptorExtractor::create("SIFT");

    cout << dictionary.size() << endl;

    DIR *pDir = nullptr;
    string imgDir("D:/WillowActions Backup/Willow 300_200/sample/");// Directory of your images. (Change this according to where you images are)
    string imgPath;
    pDir = opendir(imgDir.c_str());
    string dirName;

    Mat img_raw; // Our loaded image.
    Mat bowTry;

    struct dirent *pent = nullptr; // dirent structure for directory manipulation.

    if(pDir == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "Directory pointer could not be initialized correctly ! " << endl; // Some checking.
        return 1;
    }

    int count = 0;

    cout << "Please WAIT..." << endl;

    while((pent = readdir(pDir)) != nullptr)
    {
        if(pent == nullptr)
        {
            cout << " Dirent struct could not be initialized correctly !" << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        if(!strcmp(pent->d_name,".")||!strcmp(pent->d_name,".."))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            // LOOP trough the directory to read image one by one and extract dense SIFT
            dirName = pent->d_name;
            imgPath = imgDir+dirName; // Overall image path... feed this to imread();
            img_raw = imread(imgPath,1);// read the image to extract HOG features
            SIFT_matcher(img_raw, dictionary, bowTry, matcher);
            cout << count << endl;
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout << "no of images: " << count << endl;

    //open the file to write the resultant descriptor
    FileStorage fs1("D:/WillowActions Backup/Willow 300_200/Features_train.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);

    //write the new BOF descriptor to the file
    fs1 << "Vocabulary" << bowTry;



    fs1.release();


    #endif

   waitKey(0);
   return 0;

}
```

The function SIFT_matcher(img_raw, dictionary, bowTry, matcher) is like this:

```
void SIFT_matcher(Mat img_raw, Mat &dictionary, Mat &bowTry, Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> &matcher)
{

    Mat descriptors;
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
    DenseFeatureDetector detector(12.f,1,0.1f,10);

    detector.detect(img_raw,keypoints);

    Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> descriptorExtractor = DescriptorExtractor::create("SIFT");

    //create BOF descriptor extractor
    BOWImgDescriptorExtractor bowDE(descriptorExtractor, matcher);

    bowDE.setVocabulary(dictionary);


    //To store BOF representation of the image
    Mat bowDescriptor;

    //extract BOF descriptor from given image
    bowDE.compute(img_raw,keypoints,bowDescriptor);

    bowTry.push_back(bowDescriptor);

    bowDescriptor.release();

}
```

So, the problem is with second part. Whenever I run the second part the program stops working "programX.exe has stopped working". No errors are generated by the compiler and from the console. Maybe i have been overlooking something. Suggestions, comments and helps are much welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually it is showing at the bowDE.compute(img_raw,keypoints,bowDescriptor); and saying a segmentation fault has occurred. Any suggestions ?